# Using Java Normalizer to convert accent ascii to non-accent but to exclude some symboles

Tags: java, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

I have a set of data that have accented ascii in them. I want to convert the accent to plain English alphabets. I achieve that with the following code :

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String deAccent(String str) {
    String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```

But what this code is missing is the exclude characters, I don't know how I can exclude certain characters from the conversion, for example I want to exclude the letter "ü" from the word Düsseldorf so when I convert, it doesn't turn into Dusseldorf word. Is there a way to pass an exclude list to the method or the matcher and don't convert certain accented characters ?

Comment: I removed the groovy tag, as this looks like a pure Java question

Comment: Sure no problem, but I think java and groovy codes are pretty similar so the groovy guys can offer some solution as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use normalization to remove accents!

For example, the following letters are not asciified using your method:

- `ł`
- `đ`
- `ħ`

You may also want to split ligatures like `œ` into separate letters (i.e. `oe`).

Try this:

```
private static final String TAB_00C0 = "" +
        "AAAAAAACEEEEIIII" +
        "DNOOOOO×OUUUÜYTs" + // <-- note an accented letter you wanted 
                             //     and preserved multiplication sign
        "aaaaaaaceeeeiiii" +
        "dnooooo÷ouuuüyty" + // <-- note an accented letter and preserved division sign
        "AaAaAaCcCcCcCcDd" +
        "DdEeEeEeEeEeGgGg" +
        "GgGgHhHhIiIiIiIi" +
        "IiJjJjKkkLlLlLlL" +
        "lLlNnNnNnnNnOoOo" +
        "OoOoRrRrRrSsSsSs" +
        "SsTtTtTtUuUuUuUu" +
        "UuUuWwYyYZzZzZzs";

public static String toPlain(String source) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case 'ß':
                sb.append("ss");
                break;
            case 'Œ':
                sb.append("OE");
                break;
            case 'œ':
                sb.append("oe");
                break;
            // insert more ligatures you want to support 
            // or other letters you want to convert in a non-standard way here
            // I recommend to take a look at: æ þ ð ﬂ ﬁ
            default:
                if (c >= 0xc0 && c <= 0x17f) {
                    c = TAB_00C0.charAt(c - 0xc0);
                }
                sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```